# How can we centralize using Styled Components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[image]

I'm using a styled component.
I want to place the left red 13:18 in the same position as the time on the right and tag it underneath.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using the `display: flex` for the parent container which holds the `time` text, assuming the `time` text is also a component you can also add `display: flex` and
`flex-direction: column` property to the individual `time` text components so that they are aligned in the center

I have tried what you are trying to accomplish, check this https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-m3psy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark